# proving that pp closed under cook reductions

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, closure-properties

I tried to prove or disprove that pp is closed under cook reductions.
anyone has a idea or link to a answer?

Answer (score 2):

[PH $\subseteq$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toda%27s_theorem) P<sup>PP</sup> ​ is known to hold, so if PP is closed under Cook reductions

then ​ PH $\subseteq$ P<sup>PP</sup> $\subseteq$ PP<sup>PP</sup> $\subseteq$ PP . ​ ​ ​ ​ ( PH $\subseteq$ PP ​ is not known to hold.)

If ​ PP = [PSPACE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSPACE) ​ then ​ PP<sup>PP</sup> = PP<sup>PSPACE</sup> = PSPACE = PP .

( PP ≠ PSPACE ​ is not known to hold.)

See the [Counting Hierarchy](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:C#ch).

Comment: i don't sure if i understand your question. you said it's a open question?

Comment: I didn't ask a question here. ​ ​

Comment: i meam your answer